# Pentaho cde popup not showing table

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I have a Pentaho cde dashboard with a popup component to show a table.  This popup works ok if I load the table when the dashboard is generated.  However, I want to change the query called depending on which figure is clicked on the main dashboard page.  The table consists of detail records retrieved from a database using a cda query.

When I change a parameter containing the dataAccessId when calling the popup it does not work.  The popup fails to appear.

Anyone have any ideas how to get around this?

This works:

```
function f(e){
    render_Popup_Details.popup($(e.target));
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
function f(e){
    Dashboards.fireChange('flag_popup', 'flag_10');
    render_Popup_Details.popup($(e.target));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try updating the table before activating the popup?

```
function f(e){
    Dashboards.fireChange('flag_popup', 'flag_10');

    Dashboards.update([render_your_table_component_name]);

    render_Popup_Details.popup($(e.target));
}
```

If you're using RequireJS, then:

```
function f(e){
    this.dashboard.setParameter('flag_popup', 'flag_10');

    this.dashboard.getComponent('render_your_table_component_name').update();

    this.dashboard.getComponent('render_Popup_Details').popup($(e.target));
}
```